# Evidences that Java (JVM) behaves similar on "some/all" OS?

Tags: java, jvm

Does anybody know an official third-party study or proven test-suite that can give evidence, that the JVM will work on some/any/all operating systems the same? (For the non OS-Special functions.) Or is there evidence, that this can not be achieved anyhow?

I am looking from a security view and wonder if I need to test my Java-Software on every OS to ensure this.

Comment: The JVM has a definition of how it's supposed to work. But you can't rule out bugs in some implementations.

Comment: [TCK](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technology_Compatibility_Kit) and  [Eclipse AQAvit™](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/adoptium.aqavit)